# WebException: The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly

Tags: c#, httpclient

I am writing a simple winform application to get http response from a local modem with address 192.168.1.1:

Here is my code:

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
          using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("GET"), "http://192.168.1.1/"))
                {
                    var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
                }
}
```

Now when I run the application I get the following exception:

WebException: The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.

Note: If I change the address to an external IP address it works correctly but it can not work with 192.168.1.1.

I have searched in different sites but I could not find any solution.

Comment: a modem running a web page?

Comment: @BugFinder virtually all modems and routers serve a web page where you can change settings etc.

Comment: @BugFinder Yes I am trying to access the modem webpage.

Comment: @BertusvanZyl depends on the modem, adsl router/modems yes, pure modems as in the plug in phone line make skreachy noises do not.

Answer (score 0):

If this opens in a browser correctly, but not when using a Rest client, compare the headers the browser adds, and make sure you also send these headers. Sometimes, for example, if content-length is missing, the server refuses to service the request.

You can use a tool like fiddler to see what the html headers look like.

Comment: Yes it opens in the browser.